# Setting Next and Previous Properties

Tags: c#

I have a list of Tokens which are generated by the Tokeniser.

```cs
List<Token> tokenList = new List<Token>();
```

And here's the token class.

```cs
public class Token
{
    public Tokens TokenName { get; set; }

    public string TokenValue { get; set; }

    public Token Previous {
        get; set;
    }

    public Token Next {
        get; set;
    }

    public Token(Tokens name, string value)
    {
        TokenName = name;
        TokenValue = value;
    }
}
```

And I need to set the `Next` and `Previous` properties of each token in the list but avoid them to point `NEWLINE` or `WHITESPACE` or `TABSPACE` tokens but use their next ones.

Here's my code.

```cs
Token token = null;

foreach (Token tkn in tokenList)
{
    if (token != null)
    {
        switch (token.TokenName)
        {
            case Tokens.NEWLINE:
            case Tokens.WHITESPACE:
            case Tokens.TABSPACE:
                break;
            default:
                switch (tkn.TokenName)
                {
                    case Tokens.NEWLINE:
                    case Tokens.WHITESPACE:
                    case Tokens.TABSPACE:
                        break;
                    default:
                        tkn.Previous = token;
                        token.Next = tkn;
                        token = tkn;
                        break;
                }
                break;
       }
    }
    else
    {
        token = tkn;
    }
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Any help please?

Comment: How exactly does your code not work? What *does* it do?

Comment: The Properties are always refering to WhiteSpace tokens.

Comment: This code makes no sense.  For example you have a loop that sometimes sets a variable name token and sometimes does not.  But then it does nothing with this value.  What exactly is the point of this loop.  Please explain what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Learn to use your debugger. It'll be the best coding-related thing you ever did.

Answer (score 0):

Think I've used a lot of unnecessary code. Thanks @Lee, I've used the debugger. Setting the breakpoints showed a lot of code isn't simply executed. Here's my working code.

```
Token token = null;

foreach (Token tkn in tokenList)
{
    switch (tkn.TokenName)
    {
        case Tokens.NEWLINE:
        case Tokens.WHITESPACE:
        case Tokens.TABSPACE:
            break;
        default:
            tkn.Previous = token;
            if (token != null)
                token.Next = tkn;
            token = tkn;
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I hope this may solve your problem. Please check

```
class Program
{
    public enum TokenName { NEWLINE, WHITESPACE, TABSPACE, A, B, C};
    public class Token
    {
        public TokenName TokenName { get; set; }
        public string TokenValue { get; set; }

        public Token Previous
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Token Next
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Token(TokenName name, string value)
        {
            TokenName = name;
            TokenValue = value;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int count = 0, j=0;
        Token tkn = null;
        List<Token> tokenList = new List<Token>();

        tokenList.Add(new Token(TokenName.NEWLINE, "7"));
        tokenList.Add(new Token(TokenName.A, "1"));
        tokenList.Add(new Token(TokenName.B, "2"));
        tokenList.Add(new Token(TokenName.TABSPACE, "5"));
        tokenList.Add(new Token(TokenName.C, "3"));
        tokenList.Add(new Token(TokenName.WHITESPACE, "8"));

        foreach (Token tken in tokenList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tken.TokenName.ToString() +" "+  tken.TokenValue.ToString());
        }

        for(int i=0; i<tokenList.Count; i++)
        {
            switch (tokenList[i].TokenName)
            {
                case TokenName.NEWLINE:
                case TokenName.TABSPACE:
                case TokenName.WHITESPACE: break;

                default:

                    count++;
                    if (tkn == null)
                    {
                        tkn = tokenList[i];
                        j=i;                            
                    }

                    if (count > 1)
                    {
                        tokenList[i].Previous = tkn;
                        tkn.Next = tokenList[i];
                        tkn = tokenList[i];
                        count++;
                    }
                    break;                                        
            }                          
        }

        tkn = tokenList[j];
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tkn.TokenName.ToString() +" "+ tkn.TokenValue.ToString());
            tkn = tkn.Next;                
        }
        while (tkn != null);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what exactly did you change?

Comment: I am sure if its working as per your requirement, you can figure it out yourself.

Comment: I am not the one who asked the question. And I really don't think answers should be puzzles. A good answer will explain what's wrong with the original code, how to change it and why.